# stdout write with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting started with some modern Javascript, I decided to use Nodejs because it appears to be the most popular framework for JS on the desktop at the moment, I don't understand both why my code doesn't work and the associated error message that I get.

Consider this snippet

```
var a = 5;
var func = function(){return arguments.length;};
process.stdout.write(+func(1,2,3,a));
```

It doesn't work and it generates the following error message

```
net.js:612
    throw new TypeError('invalid data');
          ^
TypeError: invalid data
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:612:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (var_1.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I'm a C/C++ programmer and this is absolutely cryptic to me, moreover I used a `+` before invoking `func` to make sure that the result is an `integer`, so why `write` is complaining at all ?

After some nonsense adding a `+ '\n'` makes this code work

```
var a = 5;
var func = function(){return arguments.length;};
process.stdout.write(+func(1,2,3,a) + '\n');
```

Anyone can explain what's going on ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 1st argument given to [`.write()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) is expected to be a `String` or `Buffer`. `Number`s aren't allowed.

```
process.stdout.write(func(1,2,3,a).toString());
```

```
process.stdout.write(String(func(1,2,3,a)));
```

The Addition operator (`a + b`) does this conversion implicitly when concatenating `'\n'`.

Comment: `must be a String or Buffer` really ? really really really ? There is even a single meaningful reason for this choice in the design of this library ?

Comment: @user2485710 Node's streams center around Buffers, which are its way of representing byte strings/arrays/etc. It allows Strings as well because they can easily be converted to Buffers -- `if (typeof chunk === 'string') chunk = new Buffer(chunk);`.

Answer (score 2):

[You can only write strings or `Buffer`s to sockets](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.33/lib/net.js#L613-614).  (`stdout` is a socket.)  As a integer is not a string or a buffer, trying to write it to `stdout` is an error.

Concatenating a string to an integer coerces (converts) the integer to a string, which is why it worked.  You could concatenate an empty string (`i+''`) or call the integer's `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
var writeBuffer = Buffer(1);
writeBuffer[0] = 1; //Value to be written
process.stdout.write(writeBuffer);
```